# Remove from array past dates

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I have the following array with different mixed dates from different years

```
       Array
    (
        [0] => 2016-05-18
        [1] => 2016-06-18
        [2] => 2016-08-13
        [3] => 2016-09-03
        [4] => 2016-10-08
        [5] => 2016-08-06
        [6] => 2016-09-30
        [7] => 2016-09-10
        [8] => 2016-07-09
        [9] => 2016-06-13
        [10] => 2016-06-15
        [11] => 2016-07-30
        [12] => 2016-08-27
        [13] => 2016-07-02
        [14] => 2016-11-01
        [15] => 2016-09-18
        [16] => 2016-11-06
        [17] => 2016-11-07
        [18] => 2017-06-17
        [19] => 2017-06-22
        [20] => 2017-06-21
        [21] => 2017-10-01
        [22] => 2017-07-08
        [23] => 2017-05-27
        [24] => 2017-06-06
        [25] => 2017-09-09
        [26] => 2017-04-16
        [27] => 2017-09-16
        [28] => 2017-07-29
        [29] => 2017-08-05
        [30] => 2017-09-03
        [31] => 2017-06-24
        [32] => 2017-08-26
        [33] => 2017-07-22
        [34] => 2018-05-28
        [35] => 2018-06-09
        [36] => 2017-10-16
        [37] => 2017-10-28
        [38] => 2017-10-08
        [39] => 2017-11-04
        [40] => 2018-06-20
        [41] => 2018-08-05
        [42] => 2018-09-03
        [43] => 2018-06-16
        [44] => 2018-03-31
        [45] => 2019-05-25
        [46] => 2021-05-25
        [47] => 2021-05-26
        [48] => 2021-05-27
)
```

I want to remove all dates earlier than 2021 so my new array will have only the dates belonging to the current year of 2021. How can I filter the new array so all dates before 2021 will disappear?

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => 2021-05-25
        [1] => 2021-05-26
        [2] => 2021-05-27
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that loops through the array and check if the string stars with **2021** if not, delete the element.

For php 8 you can use function:
`str_starts_with(string $haystack, string $needle): bool`

For example:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){
     if(!str_starts_with('2021', $val)){
          unset($array[$key]);
     }
}
```

For previous php versions you can use `strpos`
Example:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){
     if (!strpos($val, '2021') == 0) {
          unset($array[$key]);
     }
}
```

Comment: You did not test `if(!str_starts_with('2021', $val)){`.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over each date and use the dateTime object to compare the times to see if the date has passed a set date like the begining of a year and if it hasn't then add it to the new array. See below code:

```
<?php
//array with mixed date data
$dateArray = array("2021-01-01","2016-05-18","2017-09-03","2018-06-16","2019-05-25","2021-05-25","2021-05-26","2021-05-27");

//the day you want to have everyday after (in this case the start of 2021)
$setDate = "2021-01-01";

//array where the dates greater than then the set date will be stored.
$newTimesArray = array();
$setDateObj = new \DateTime($setDate); // moved outside of loop
foreach ($dateArray as $date) {
    $given_date = new \DateTime($date); //convert string to a date time object
    if ($given_date >= $setDateObj) { //if the date is greater than or equal to "2021-01-01" add it to the new array
          $newTimesArray[]=$date;
        }
}

//print the results
echo print_r($newTimesArray,true);
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa i have updated my answer with your suggestion

Comment: Now I'll bring to your attention that datetime objects are completely unnecessary because the date strings are big-endian and can be safely compared as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You have hashtag array-filter and PHP has array_filter function:

```php
$dates = [
    '2016-05-18',
    '2018-03-31',
    '2019-05-25',
    '2021-05-25',
    '2021-05-26',
    '2021-05-27',
];

function myFilter($dt) {
    $year = date('Y',strtotime($dt));
    return $year > 2020;
}
print_r(array_values(array_filter($dates, 'myFilter')));
```