# Filter out time values in a flat array if less than current time

Tags: php, arrays, time, filtering, natural-sort

I have a variable that stores current time with `$current_time` and another variable with an array of time stored in `$time_slot` I am looking for a way around to unset from array variable `$time_slot` all array of time that is less than the `$current_time` I tried below code but it didn't work:

```
$current_time = '4:00';
$time_slot = ['1:00','3:00','15:00','19:00'];

  // removing the deleted value from array
    if (($key = array_search($current_time, $time_slot)) !== false) {
        if($current_time>$time_slot){
        unset($time_slot[$key]);
        }
    }

 print_r($time_slot);
```

Comment: What have  you tried to resolve the problem? You're not even comparing time data, but strings - maybe you should convert these strings to stuff that **really** represents time?

Comment: Related: [Remove from array past dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68505375/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your timeslots to a `DateTime` instance which will make it easier to compare your values.

```
$date = new \DateTime('15:00');
var_dump($date);
```

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2022-10-20 15:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

In the snippet below, I unset the index of the timeslot if it's "expired"

```
<?php

$current_time = '4:00';
$time_slot = ['1:00','3:00','15:00','19:00'];

$current_date = new \DateTime($current_time);

foreach($time_slot as  $index => $value) {
    if ($current_date > new \DateTime($value)) unset($time_slot[$index]);
}
var_dump($time_slot);
```

[demo](https://ideone.com/wrhlv4)
<s>[demo](https://ideone.com/nVslQ5)</s>

Answer (score 1):

By making [natural sorting comparisons](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php), you can call `array_filter()` to weed out the times which are smaller than the current time.  `strnatcmp()` returns a 3-way result (`-1`, `0`, and `1`) -- if `-1` then the the first value is smaller than the second value.

You don't need to create new DateTime objects on every iteration.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aoZP3))

```
var_export(
    array_filter(
        $time_slot,
        fn($v) => strnatcmp($current_time, $v) === -1
    )
);
```